# How to use case statement in select into clause while creating stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to create a Stored Procedure using below code. But i am getting compilation error.

```
create or replace procedure sp(enm number, com_stat out varhar2)
as
begin
select
(case
when (sal > 2000 and comm is not null) then ('High Sal')
when (sal < 2000 and comm is null) then ('No Comm')
end) into com_stat 
from emp1 ;
dbms_output.put_line(com_stat);
end;
```

Can anyone please help me on this issue.

Thanks,
Subash

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Datatype is `varchar2`, not `varhar2`.

Apart from that, you can omit those brackets.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure sp(enm number, com_stat out varchar2)
  2  as
  3  begin
  4    select case when sal > 2000 and comm is not null then 'High Sal'
  5                when sal < 2000 and comm is null     then 'No Comm'
  6           end
  7      into com_stat
  8      from emp1 ;
  9  end;
 10  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
```

However, there's high possibility that procedure will raise `too_man_rows` as there's no `WHERE` clause which would restrict `select` to return a single value. It is probably

```
where emp1.empno = enm
```

or something like that, missing after line #8.